# Duda con CSS y margenes de pantalla

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un archivo js que cargo en cada pagina del proyecto y que analiza la resolución de la pantalla.

```
if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
//Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones mayores a 1024
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mayor1024.css">');
} else if ($(window).width() == 1024) {
//Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones de 1024
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
}  else if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
//Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones menores de 1024
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
}
```

Tengo dos archivos css donde en el menor1024.css tengo lo siguiente:

```
#bloque {
padding-left: 0%;
padding-right: 0%;
}

#formulario {
padding-left: 0%;
padding-right: 0%;
}
```

y en el mayor1024.css tengo esto:

```
#bloque {
padding-left: 5%;
padding-right: 5%;
}

#formulario {
padding-left: 20%;
padding-right: 20%;
}
```

Por ejemplo en la página de NOTICIAS cargo una tabla dentro de un div con esta definicion:

```
<div id="bloque" class="ui text container">
    (va la tabla)
</div>
```

despues cuando uno elige una noticia dada, se llena en la pantalla dentro de un div con esta estructura:

```
<div id="formulario" class="ui text container">
    (va el desarrollo de la noticia)
</div>
```

Esto lo hice porque por pantalla para que la noticia no ocupara todo el ancho de la pantalla (y se dificulte la lectura) le ponia un padding a los lados del 20% de la pantalla. 
 Ahora bien, cuando iba a un dispositivo movil, pasaba cualquier cosa, se veía horrible. 
 De esta forma si el dispositivo es móvil, toma el ancho de la pantalla y se debería ver bien. 
 Pero el problema que tengo es que en el móvil sigo teniendo un margen a los lados y no me toma todo el ancho de la pantalla... a que se debería este problema ?

Comment: El móvil no tendrá una resolución de pantalla igual o superior? Por ej. 1080 x 1920 en este caso tomaría el mayor1024.css

Comment: Sabés que en eso estaba pensando ? Eso estaba viendo que cómo haces hoy en dia para discriminar si es un dispositivo movil ? teniendo en cuenta que tenes unos dispositivos con unas resoluciones terribles ?

Comment: Pffffffffff tiene 1080 x 1920

Comment: porque no utilizas medias querys del css3

Comment: no se lo que es eso de "medias querys del css3"

Comment: Yo lo haría solo con [css3 y @media](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con algo así, primero detectamos si se está conectando desde un dispositivo móvil caso si carga el estilo menor1024.css y caso contrario carga el estilo de acuerdo a la resolución de pantalla.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  var device = navigator.userAgent

  if (device.match(/Iphone/i)|| device.match(/Ipod/i)|| device.match(/Android/i)|| device.match(/J2ME/i)|| device.match(/BlackBerry/i)|| device.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)|| device.match(/Opera Mini/i)|| device.match(/IEMobile/i)|| device.match(/Mobile/i)|| device.match(/Windows Phone/i)|| device.match(/windows mobile/i)|| device.match(/windows ce/i)|| device.match(/webOS/i)|| device.match(/palm/i)|| device.match(/bada/i)|| device.match(/series60/i)|| device.match(/nokia/i)|| device.match(/symbian/i)|| device.match(/HTC/i)) { 
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
  } else {
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    //Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones mayores a 1024
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mayor1024.css">');
    } else if ($(window).width() == 1024) {
    //Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones de 1024
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
    }  else if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    //Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones menores de 1024
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
    }
  } 

</script>
```

[Detectar versión para móviles y redireccionar web o enlace con JavaScript](http://www.blogginred.com/2016/01/detectar-version-para-moviles-y.html#.WZHlnFHyjIU)

No sé si esto es lo ideal, te recomendaría ver si no sería conveniente usar un framework tipo Bootstrap que ayuda mucho en estas horas y no es difícil de aprender a utilizar:

[Bootstrap (framework)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(framework))

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: pero si tengo que detectar que tipo de movil esta usando, me vuelvo loco !!! Estoy usando Semantic-UI

Comment: En este caso sólo verifica si es uno de esos móviles y carga el estilo más pequeño caso contrario entiende que no se trata de un móvil y verifica la resolución para cargar el estilo correspondiente.

Comment: Pero si estás utilizando Semantic-UI (nunca lo he utilizado) mirando ahora veo que es responsive, quizás por ahí podrías sacarle ventaja. [Responsive UI Examples](https://semantic-ui.com/examples/responsive.html)

Comment: si eso estaba viendo... tengo que trabajar con la grilla !!!

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución que funciona bien. Con esta solución no analizo la resolución de la pantalla sino que obtengo el ancho del navegador

```
if ($(window.innerWidth() > 1024) {
//Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones mayores a 1024
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mayor1024.css">');
} else if ($(window.innerWidth() == 1024) {
//Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones de 1024
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
}  else if ($(window.innerWidth() < 1024) {
//Aqui cargara una hoja de estilos para resoluciones menores de 1024
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menor1024.css">');
}
```

uso la misma rutina en js que tengo definida pero cambio $(window).width() por $(window.innerWidth()
la solución anda perfecto...

Comment: la ventaja de este método es que también responde en la ventana de la PC ya que va acomodando automaticamente los margenes